# Passing control id to javascript from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am making a dynamic image gallary in which images of a folder are listed in div.
I want to increase there size on onclick by javascript.

I am assigning onclick event from code-behind like this

```
   int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; ;
             for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
                img.ID = "projectimg" + i.ToString();
                img.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                img.Height = 120;
                img.Width = 120;
                img.ToolTip = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                img.OnClientClick = "incsize('" + "contentPlace_" + img.ID + "')";
              }
```

where incsize is my function in JavaScript

```
function incsize(imgid)
{
    alert("jjj");
    //do some thing here as
    var img = document.getElementById(imgid);
}
```

But this is not working. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: why is this called javascript? :)

Comment: are you trying to pass some id from asp.net webforms code-behind to a javascript function?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try this.</strike>

Suppose you have an Image in your aspx like this.

```
<asp:Image ID="MyImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/some-image.png"/>
```

Assign a JavaScript o`onclick` attribute like this on code behind like this.

```
string script = String.Format("javascript:return incsize('{0}');", MyImage.ClientID);
MyImage.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
```

Now call it in JavaScript like this.

```
function incsize(imgid) {
    //alert("jjj");
    //do some thing here as
    var img = document.getElementById(imgid);
}
```

---

**Please ask clearly what you want in your future questions.**

Do this inside your loop.

```
ImageButton img = new ImageButton(); //Image img = new Image(); 
img.ID = "projectimg" + i.ToString(); 
img.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(); 
img.Height = 120; 
img.Width = 120; 
img.ToolTip = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
img.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
string script = String.Format("javascript:return incsize('{0}');", img.ID);
img.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
```

Comment: ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
                //Image img = new Image();
                img.ID = "projectimg" + i.ToString();
                img.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                img.Height = 120;
                img.Width = 120;
                img.ToolTip = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
this is my imagebutton and this is in a loop to create more then one imagebuttons.

Comment: why COULDN'T you elaborate all these things before hand. looks like one have to ask the question and fetch the answer for you.

Comment: my code body is very large it would have taken alot of page space if u want that i can edit it !

i am making connection from DB and geeting links of images and want to add runtime controls in page and to have a javascript function associated with it in which i pass my imageID and enlarge the image.

Comment: ok that worked but how to increase size of image in javascript i tried 
            
var img = document.getElementById(imgid);
            img.style.height = '300px';
            img.style.width = '300px';
but i does increase size but the image hides after 1 sec!!!!

Comment: you should ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

test this:

```
img.OnClientClick = "incsize('" + "contentPlace_" + img.ID + "')";
```

you had forget single qutation mark

Comment: <input type="image" name="ctl00$contentPlace$projectimg2" id="contentPlace_projectimg2" title="7/3/2011 12:18:33 AM" src="ProjectImages/5168Tulips.jpg" onclick="incsize(&#39;contentPlace_projectimg2&#39;);" style="height:120px;width:120px;" /> this is the html code which i got from this.